# How do you get the timestamp from web page

Tags: objective-c, ios

What's the easiest way to get the timestamp from a web page with objective-c (iOS sdk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "timestamp from a web page".

All an HTTP server dishes up to its client on a GET for a URL is a stream of octets and an assortment of response headers. The HTTP server will likely hand you back DATE header, but since the simply gives you the time the response was sent back, it's not likely to do you much good.

Comment: What I really want is to know when the page was last updated/modified.

Comment: No can do. Conceptually, there's no relationship between a URL and a filesystem entry or anything else that might have a "last updated" value. For all the client knows, the server is making up the response data on the fly. To get what you want, the HTTP server needs to dish up a response header containing the desired data (or if returning HTML/XML, insert the required data &mdash; say, as a <META> element &mdash; in the content body.

Comment: "Last-Modified" is a standard HTTP header, though it doesn't necessarily have to be a filesystem timestamp.

Comment: Yes. but the header is not **required**. You can't depend on its presence. `last-modified` is for cache control.

Comment: Thanks. What I was trying to do is probably better handled with an RSS feed since there is no dependable way to get "Last-Modified".